# updating spreadsheet using gdata python api

Tags: python, gdata, google-sheets-api

READ THE UPDATE AT THE END FIRST
Here's my code :

```
spreadsheet_key = "0AhBYO002ygGgdDZQTW5pTVhLdjM4NlhHbXJ1cVRCd3c"
worksheet_id = "od6"
spr_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
spr_client.email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
spr_client.password = '<pwd>'
spr_client.source = 'Example Spreadsheet Writing Application'
spr_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

dicti = {}
dicti['Name'] = 'A'
dicti['Metric Name'] = 'A2' 
dicti['Completed Units'] = 10
dicti['Team Size'] = 2
entry = spr_client.InsertRow(dicti, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
```

Every time I run this code this error comes on the last time:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Please tell me how I should proceed...

Here's where the error comes in the InsertRow function :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py in InsertRow
      new_custom.column = k
      new_custom.text = v
      new_entry.custom[new_custom.column] = new_custom
    # Generate the post URL for the worksheet which will receive the new entry.
    post_url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/%s/%s/private/full'%(
        key, wksht_id) 
    return self.Post(new_entry, post_url, 
        converter=gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsListFromString)
```

**UPDATE:** After fixing this code to this:

```
dicti = {}
dicti['Name'] = 'A'
dicti['Metric Name'] = 'A2' 
dicti['Completed Units'] = '10'
dicti['Team Size'] = '2'
```

I get this error now:

```
{'status': 400, 'body': 'Attribute name &quot;Name&quot; associated with an element type &quot;ns1:Metric&quot; must be followed by the &#39; = &#39; character.', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write string values when using the gdata API, so your 'Team Size' and 'Completed Units' variables will cause errors unless they are converted to strings. Also, you should be aware that the column names as referred to by the API do not retain your capitalization, etc. (your `Metric Name` column needs to be referred to as `metricname`). Therefore you also have to change how they appear in the dictionary (note that this assumes your column headers already exist, since the API needs to know how to write the dictionary):

```
dicti = {}
dicti['name'] = 'A'
dicti['metricname'] = 'A2' 
dicti['completedunits'] = '10'
dicti['teamsize'] = '2'
entry = spr_client.InsertRow(dict, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
```

And as a side note (since this tripped me up for a bit), the same is true when using `CellQuery` objects and declaring the `max` and `min` values for ranges. Hope that helps avoid some confusion :)

Comment: @RacketDonkey
Thank you so very much

I got this error now :
{'status': 400, 'body': 'Attribute name &quot;Name&quot; associated with an element type &quot;ns1:Metric&quot; must be followed by the &#39; = &#39; character.', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}

Could you please help me out... I have gone sleepless for too long trying to get this to work.. :(

Comment: @AniqueAkhtar Looking at the error code, are you using XML to assign values to the dictionary by any chance?

Comment: Nop...
I am hard coding it... Just like the way I showed you..

But I am using Django...

Comment: Actually, is your `entry` variable declared exactly as written? You are referring to `dict` in the `InsertRow()` call but defining the dictionary as `dicti` above.

Comment: Sorry That's a typo... it is dicti in my code..
I haven't used dict anywhere in the code
Waiting for your answer...

Comment: Here is the code where the error generated from :
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py in PostOrPut
              'body': result_body}
      else:
        raise RequestError, {'status': server_response.status,
            'reason': 'Redirect received, but redirects_remaining <= 0',
            'body': result_body}
    else:
      raise RequestError, {'status': server_response.status,
          'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body} ...

Comment: Updating the answer now - you need to convert the column names before writing.

Comment: Are you saying I need to decapitalize my name and also remove the spaces...
let me try that

Comment: Yeah, you got it. A test of your exact case is working for me right now, so we'll see if we can get it all sorted out for you :)

Comment: Wow !!
Six hours scratching my head and you solved it in a few minutes...

Anyways... the data is being posted in the spreadsheet..
Is there any way to update it... as in replace the old data with this one ?

And also can I also calculate values on spreadsheet by formulas from other columns ?

Thanks again... you have been a great help..

Comment: @AniqueAkhtar Happy it helps :) If you want, we can continue in chat (you'll need 20 reputation, so you could accept this answer and another one to a question you have asked and we can talk there).

Comment: Yay...
I got 15 reputation points... But i have no idea where the chat is... Do I need to add you somewhere ??

Comment: @AniqueAkhtar Ah, sorry, I thought accepting an answer got you five points (not two). As for updating data, if you have the full set of data in your program and want to update the sheet, I have usually cleared all of the cells in the sheet (using a CellQuery and setting the cell values to ''), and then added the data. I would read up on a bit on updating/modifying Google spreadsheets with gdata (there are a few good examples scattered about). If you are still having trouble, definitely ask another question (I'll keep an eye out :) ). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks... I found this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850257/using-python-gdata-to-clear-the-rows-in-worksheet-before-adding-data
It was pretty good..
:D
You Made my day :)

Comment: Haha, I was just looking for that! Glad it helps, and good luck with everything!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to input column name in your:

```
Spreadsheet('name','metricname','completedunits','teamsize')
```

You can read more about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=481&colspec=Opened%20Stars%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Summary).